# code porting from 32bit to 64bit

Tags: linux, 64-bit

I am trying to port 32bit code to 64bit linux machine. Are there any compiler flags for 64bit posrting warning on Linux.

There are +w2 -m64 flags for SUN. Could anyone give me information for flags similar to this one?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the answer you are looking for, but you could try replace as many `int` as possible with int32_t in a first porting phase.
Also look at the other answer.
(No I can not comment, seems I have too little rep...)

Comment: On AMD64 linux, int == int32_t.  long == int64_t.  Your suggestion is to change int to unsigned int, which if anything will introduce bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try `gcc -Wall -Wconversion -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wcast-qual`

Actually, read the gcc man page, there are a ton of warnings, and some of them may be helpful only if your code doesn't produce a flood of them for things you know aren't actually a problem.  -Wall, -pedantic, and -Wextra are meta-flags that turn on a bunch of warnings.  -Wall includes many of the important ones that will occur when you try a 64bit build of code that does bad things.

`-Werror` (turn warnings into errors) might be useful to avoid having to `make clean` after fixing some but not all errors.